# Key value pair not getting added to my dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to add an item to my dictionary. profileURL contains the correct value as I have seen from what the print statement gives me but for some reason the dictionary is not creating a new entry with it. Any solutions?

Here is my code:

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
    if error != nil {
        return
    }
    if let profileURL = url?.absoluteString {
        print("SHOULD BE DATA HERE:   ", profileURL)
        databaseValues["profileUrl"] = profileURL
    }
})
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access the value in the dictionary? I suspect this is probably an async problem.

Comment: Why do you exit the function if there is no error ?

Comment: @radioaktiv You read that backward, it exits if there *is* an error.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery It was an async issue, thanks!